# как добавить возможность передавать коду другие файлы и каталоги прямо в командной строке?

Tags: python

изучаю python по книге Byte of Python и немного не понимаю как реализовать следующую задачу:

Ещё одним возможным улучшением была бы возможность передавать сценарию другие файлы и каталоги прямо в командной строке. Эти имена можно получать из списка
sys.argv и добавлять к нашему списку source при помощи метода extend класса list.

и вот мой код:

```
import os, time as t

# Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать, собираются в список.

source = ['"C:\\my documents"']

# Резервные копии должны храниться в основном каталоге резерва.

target_dir = 'D:\\backup'

today = os.path.join(target_dir, t.strftime('%Y%m%d'))

if not os.path.exists(today):
    os.mkdir(today) # создание каталога, если он отсутствует
    print('Каталог успешно создан', today)

now = t.strftime('%H%M%S.zip')

comment = input('Введите имя zip архива --> ')

if len(comment) == 0: # Если пользователь ничего не ввел, то имя zip архива - now
    target = os.path.join(today, now)
else:
    target = os.path.join(today, comment.replace(' ', '_') + '.zip')

# Используем команду "zip" для помещения файлов в zip-архив:

zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

# Запускаем создание резервной копии:

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Ценятся развернутые ответы. Всем ответившим огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import argparse
def createParser ():   # парсер аргументов коммандной строки
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   parser.add_argument ('-arg', '--argument')
   return parser
        
parser = createParser() 
namespace = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    
print(namespace.argument) # отобразит значение аргумента, в данном случае file.txt
```

Скрипт вызывать так:

```
python script.py -arg file.txt
```